# Papers for Teaching an Introductory Course in Image & Signal Processing

Tags: image-processing, filters, digital, self-study

I'm preparing a digital signal/image processing introductory course and, besides the theory and practices I want the students to read and discuss a couple of research papers during the last one or two classes. It doesn't matter if the papers are new I just want to expose the students some first hand research material in its original format. Which papers could you recommend me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let them read the paper about the [Non Local Means Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_means):

- [Antoni Buades, Bartomeu Coll, Jean Michel Morel - On image Denoising Methods](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.100.81).

The paper is readable and it is a great introductory to the Denoising operation in the context of Image Processing.
Also the Non Local Means is a very decent method (Result wise) even in our time.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you want something not too technically complex and cover the key concepts. The one that really jumps to mind is Canny's edge detector paper. Beyond that I guess it depends on what specific topics you cover. Here are a few ideas:

- Canny 1986, A Computational Approach to Edge Detection - the Canny filter paper. It is quite easy to understand and covers a widely used function.
- Bergholm 1987, Edge focusing - Paper on multiscale filtering. I guess not that popular a topic but I really like the paper, its well written and easy to understand.
- Chan & Vese 2001, Active contours without edges - Quite a widely cited paper, although perhaps not a great example, I find most of it quite impenetrable. First couple of sections are OK though and maybe more depending on your focus.
- Bleau & Leon 2000, Watershed-Based Segmentation and Region Merging - This paper is a bit of a beast (50+ pages) but is surprisingly clear and introduces things quite rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

- Sylvain Paris and Frédo Durand 2006, A Fast Approximation of the Bilateral Filter using a Signal Processing Approach - Very well-articulated paperwork.